# Terminal: get rid of cursor flicker

Tags: terminal

I am printing to the same line over and over with a while loop to monitor progress.

```
echo; while true; do 
    sleep 0.1; 
    echo -en "\e[1A"; 
    run | some |code | awk '{print}'; 
done;
```

Prints my output to the same line every time.

However, there is a buffer problem: the cursor flickers between the echo and the print statement.

How do I get rid of the terminal cursor flicker in my status while loop?

Perhaps a different question, but still a solution: how to temporarily suppress the cursor after a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce flicker by combining the echo into the **`awk`** command.  For instance:

```
echo; while true; do 
    sleep 0.1; 
    run | some |code | awk '{printf("\033[A%s\n", $0); }'; 
done;
```

The (nonstandard) **`\e`** is equivalent to **`\033`**, and you do not really need the repeat-count **`1`**.